# VB 2010: Console application prints some superscript number characters as normal

Tags: vb.net, console-application, superscript

I just have a small issue with a Visual Basic (2010 Express) .NET application I'm making. It's a console-based application and I want it to print superscript numbers.
Well, I've found out the superscript numbers from Charmap and my code is this:

```
Public Module MainModule
    Public Sub Main()
        Console.Write(GetExponentialNumAsStr(12345, 12345)) 'This must be printed as 12345¹²³⁴⁵
        Console.ReadKey(True)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetExponentialNumAsStr$(Number As Double, Exponent%)
        If Exponent = 1 Then Return Number : Exit Function
        Return Number.ToString & Exponent.ToString.Replace("-", "⁻").Replace("0", "⁰").Replace("1", "¹").Replace("2", "²").Replace("3", "³").Replace("4", "⁴").Replace("5", "⁵").Replace("6", "⁶").Replace("7", "⁷").Replace("8", "⁸").Replace("9", "⁹")
    End Function
End Module
```

Okay, the `GetExponentialNumAsString$` function works well and gives **12345¹²³⁴⁵**, which is okay (checked through `Immediate window`), but the only problem is that while printing the same in the Console view gives this:

```
123451²345
```

Why is it that only 2 is shown in superscript form and why not the other digits also?
If I try printing 0 to 9 as superscript, it comes like this:

```
1²345678?°
```

Well 9 is gone, but the other digits is what confusing me. Only 2 and 0 are shown in superscript form!

---

I also tried copy-pasting all the superscript numbers in a `Command Prompt` window... this is what came:
[image: Command Prompt's display of ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰]
Command Prompt, in fact, when copy-pasted, shows correctly!

---

So what should I do? Convert those superscript numbers to **CP-437 (DOS)** encoding and then display it?
Please help me! Thank you everybody!

---

***EDIT:*** I've tried saving that thing as a file in my Desktop using CP-437 encoding. What appears is like **1ý345678?ø**. And when converted back manually to UTF-8 or one of the general encodings, it comes back as **1²345678?°**.
Also tried using `ECHO ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰>Hello123.TXT` and what came was the same thing as above. So... has no use.
And I am a bit sure that CP-437 has those superscript characters because Command Prompt can display them!!!

Comment: You should really turn `Option Strict On`.  Your function is strange.  In one case it returns a `Double` and in another it returns a `String`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Umm... in all the cases it returns a `String`... Oh wait now I get it. I guess it would be better if I use `Return Number.ToString()`, right?

Comment: But what's the difference actually? Finally, the `Double` value will get converted to `String` value as the Function's type is `String`, right? Whatever thanks for helping!

Comment: This is entirely normal lossage when you try to display Unicode glyphs in a console that operates in code page 437.  The .NET Encoding class plays a role, it makes an effort to translate some glyphs to equivalent 437 code page bytes.  But it is quirky, it doesn't handle 9 for some mysterious reason, thus producing a ?  The 2 and the 0 do have roughly equivalent glyphs in 437, the 0 is actually the temperature symbol.  If you want more predictable results then you need to switch to UTF8 and select a non-Terminal font, like Consolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Hans Passant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936069/#comment71103405_41936069), the trick is to set the Console's output encoding to UTF-8, such as

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
```

And look! It comes!
[image: Resulting output using UTF-8 encoding]